# How to send wireless sensor data through a firewall bidirectionally without opening a port using Python?

Tags: python, webserver, sensors, raspberry-pi

I'm new to this forum and relatively new to python but have been playing around with sockets/google app engine/django etc… I'm at a loss on how to best design this app and what tools to use for it. Any people with more exp

**Hardware:** I have a Raspberry Pi behind a firewall that collects wireless sensor data. I would like to access that data from an outside web server (aka google app engine or ec2 server).

**Goal:** The goal is to have users in different homes (like my mom, grandpa etc living separately with their own pi's) be able to check their data on the web on a centralized server. I should also be able to initiate actions on the Pi's so the data should be sent bi-directionally. Ideally without having to open up firewall ports (dummy proof).

**What I did so far:**
I was able to create sockets on the PI to send data to a django server (ec2) but I had to open ports for that.

**Questions:**

1. I'd like to do this with *python*, *no open ports*, *bidirectional* data.
2. How do you deal with failsafes such as:

   - The internet going down.
   - Missing server readings.
   - Power outages.
3. Could this be solved just by syncing a database between the Pi and web server?

I realize this is a very broad question but perhaps it's less about the exact tools and more about the techniques one would use for this particular type of project? Tools, techniques, paradigms or general experiences are all welcome.

Thanks everyone,

David

Comment: From what I read, your question can also by restated as "How can I bypass firewalls in Python?".  If this was a one-off type thing, or a few prototypes, you could probably dial and create a (reverse) ssh tunnel.  If this were anything more, I'd be more inclined to just use an API that posts & gets data via HTTP.  It's much easier for your PI to "fetch" a set of instructions at a regular interval than have your servers communicate back with it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess my question was multipart. I know I can just "fetch" instructions when I want them. The problem is that when I click the "turn the light on" button on the webserver I would like for it to do it then and there and not the next time it's scheduled to check for data. This will mostly be used for watering the plants but still .

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  But you're trying to bypass firewalls, which isn't really easy.  You can look into how services like LogMeIn and Apple Remote Control work.  I know LogMeIn has some whitepapers online, and are upfront about all the magic they do to bypass firewalls... you'd essentially have to re-implement that.

Comment: Good points. I'm trying to find some documentation. Ignoring the firewall issues for now how would you design a way to transfer data between the pi and server in an asynchronous method